# Duplicate items on Woocommerce cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having difficulty removing duplicate items on a Woocommerce cart page on Wordpress. It shows a **Shipping Options** dropdown twice (`shipping_method[0]` according to Safari's inspect feature). The first drop down it shows doesn't actually change the calculation at all so, it's pretty redundant. The second one (on the right hand side if you view the picture) works fine and I'd like to keep that.

I've found where the drop down exists in `cart-shipping.php`, but when I comment out the code, it removes both instances. Is there any way to remove just the first instance?

There are also four **Proceed to checkout** buttons on the cart, which is uber overkill. Is there a way to remove those too? On the right hand side there is an **Update Cart** button with a **Proceed to Checkout** button underneath. Those would be ideal to keep but the rest shouldn't be there.

[The Live Site](http://eshop.livingpurenatural.com/cart/)
[image: Screen Shot of Cart]

Comment: Pretty sure this is specific to your theme. It appears to be showing the cart totals template 2x.

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking, I couldn't see the **Flatsome** theme whilst using FTP, but can through CPanel. I've managed to remove the final **Proceed to Checkout** button, but the other two unwanted buttons seem to not be in  'cart.php'.

Comment: The cart totals are in `cart-totals.php` and added via `add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'woocommerce_cart_totals', 10 );`. that's what it looks like your theme is displaying twice (possibly added to a second hook without being removed). If you look at a default theme: http://tinyurl.com/ocawo9q you will see this only displays once.

Comment: Thank you @helgatheviking, your last comment especially proved very helpful. I'm still discovering how Wordpress works and didn't think about the actions. Many thanks! The issue is now fixed if you want to check the **Live Link** in my question. I owe you a brew!! Thanks again

Comment: I'm always open to [margaritas](https://inspirepay.com/pay/helgatheviking). :) Can you post an answer that explains what you did in case someone else needs it?

Comment: Sure, from <code>cart.php</code> I commented out <code><?php do_action('woocommerce_cart_collaterals'); ?></code>, which seemed to be the action for injecting **Sub-total**, **Total** and the **Dropdown Menu**. <code><input type="submit" class="checkout-button secondary expand button" name="proceed" value="<?php _e( 'Proceed to Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></code> and <code><input type="submit" class="checkout-button secondary expand button" name="proceed" value="<?php _e( 'Proceed to Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></code>, both seemed to remove the unwanted buttons.